# Use DocumentTermMatrix for article lines

Tags: matrix, text-mining

I have 2 files:

- one with ~1000 lines. Each line corresponds to one newspaper article which is already cleaned (punctuation, upper case, irrelevant words,etc).
- one with ~1000 lines and only one column which is the corresponding article origin.
  Article from line X in first file finds its orginal in line X from 2nd file.

I used the DocumentTermMatrix where I can do a lot of study on the words frequency but I cannot work at article granularity level.

I'd like to do 2 matrices

- 1st with article as rows (so corresponding to a row from my file) and all possible words as columns (based on first file only)
- 2nd with origin as rows (from 2nd file) and all possible words as columns (from my 1st file) allowing me to establish classification between origin and words.

Can you let me know how best could I build these matrices in R with or without DocumentTermMatrix?

I could split first the file into 1000 files with another tool and then use DocumentTermMatrix but I'd prefer and R script managing directly the merged files with one article per line.